# I cannot change privileges for folder with chmod on CentOS

Tags: postgresql, centos7

On CentOS 7 server for the folder /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/ I do:

```
sudo chmod -Rf 755 /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/
```

But it doesn't change privileges for folder. But sometimes it changes for 10-15 minutes. Later when I try again, it prints - "No permissions". What is the problem???

Before:

```
drwx------ 16 postgres 4096 Dec 20 12:56 /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/
```

After:

```
drwxr-xr-x 16 postgres 4096 Dec 20 12:56 /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/
```

Comment: what is the ouput of ls -ld `/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/` ? before and after chmod ?

Comment: There's no reason you should be messing around with this. What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @alizade: Please use the `edit` button to add information to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is "by design" - only the postgres user should have access to that folder. My understanding is that postgres fixes this whenever a database is initialised.